# Send a Happy Birthday email to employees on their birthday

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I am very new to sharepoint and am trying out the workflows. I faced some difficulties in building a workflow where it can send happy birthday email to employees on their birthday. Hope to get some help here.

[image]

Comment: what error you are getting or where you are struck?

Comment: You have list with all users and their birthdays or you are want to requesting UPS or AAD? You should create Flow simply in Flow cause you need trigged 1perDay not create a Flow from some Library List or Library.

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan Hi there, i do not get any error yet, as i do not know what to fill in the column that i have boxed in my image above.

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška I do have a list of user with their birthday which i have import from excel into the sharepoint list. What doe you mean by create flow simply in flow? Sorry i am a very new to sharepoint as well as creating workflow in sharepoint.

Comment: I created this flow for you, but the question is Put On Hold, so edit it that you want to help to create the flow and i will answer with the whole solution.

Comment: Do you need still help?